# Recursive Power Function Step

Tags: python

**I have this:**

```
def main():

    input1 = input('Enter an integer for the base:')
    input2 = input('Enter an integer for the exponent:')


main()
```

**This is what I fully need to do:**

Create a main, and a power function. **Half done.**

prompt the user to enter an integer for the base of the power. **Done.**

prompt the user for an integer for the exponent of the power. **Done.**

call the power function and print its returned value. **Can do.**

The recursive power function, power(base,exponent), must recursively calculate the value of the power and then return it. **Need help with this.**

I have been trying to learn the recursive function stuff the past two days, and cannot seem to wrap my head around it. Could someone provide me a walk through of this, so I can mess around with it, so I can understand it better? Thanks!

Comment: I tried explaining the basics of recursion in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30214677/1903116). You might want to go though that once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You basically need to multiply a given number to itself until the power reaches zero:

```
def power(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return 1

    if y >= 1:
        return x * power(x, y - 1)
```