# Write a recursive Python function, given a non-negative integer N, to calculate and return the sum of its digits

Tags: python

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
def sumDigits(n):
    if n == 0:
        print 0
    else:
        print n%10 + sumDigits(n/10)
sumDigits(35)
```

Comment: One of the key parts of recursion is returning values from the recursive function. You might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30214677/1903116) to know more about the basics of recursion.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work you need the *sum*.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to *print* the answer  (as opposed to returning it)?

Comment: Yeah, i have to return it. Can u please make the code work?

Comment: Have you considered adding `return`? This isn't a tutorial service.

Comment: Try formatting according to PEP 8; e.g. function names should be all lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.x, note that you need to use `//` to perform integer division, as `/` will perform `float` (true) division even with two integers.

In any case, the function needs to `return` the values, not just `print` them.

```
def sumDigits(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return n%10 + sumDigits(n//10)
```

Then it will work as intended

```
>>> sumDigits(35)
8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works for numbers (and strings!) of all lengths.

```
def sumDigits(n):
    n = str(n)

    if n is "":
        # Base Case: Return 0 when there is nothing left
        return 0    
    else:
        # Default Case: Return the first number + sum of the rest)
        return int(n[0]) + sumDigits(n[1:])    


>>> print sumDigits(359)
>>> 17
```

This, when written out, will look like this:

sumDigits(359) = 3 + sumDigits(59) = 3 + 5 + sumDigits(9) = 3 + 5 + 9 + 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to return values instead of printing values.

Try this:

```
def sumDigits(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return n%10 + sumDigits(n//10)

>>> sumDigits(41)
5

>>> sumDigits(31)
4
```

You can also use `and` operator to leverage the equality check when n is 0.

```
def sumDigits(n):
    return n and n%10 + sumDigits(n//10)
```

Here, `n%10 + sumDigits(n//10)` will be evaluated only when `n` is non-zero.

Use `//` as it gives the quotient on division in which the digits after the decimal point are removed.

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to make the recursive call `sumDigits( n / 10)` it expects to have a value returned. When it fails to get that value because the function doesn't return anything, you receive the error.

This could prove useful: [Python Functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)