# recursively multiplying 2 with an exponent?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

How would I write a code that takes 2 to the exponent x? recursively?
I have been trying but i have no clue. Here is what I have.

```
def recursiveExponent(x):
    if x<=0:
        return 1
    return = 2* recursiveExponent(x - 1)
```

This code does not work at all. What I want to do is have the user input an exponent and recursively calculate 2 to the input exponent.

Examples:

recursiveExponent(2)---> 4, where 2^2 is 4

recursiveExponent(4)----->16, where 2^4 is 16

Comment: remove `=` after the `return`. If you are interested in recursion, you might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30214531/1903116) as well.

Comment: This is also going to create an infinite recursion at the moment, because it will keep calling `recursiveExponent` for larger and larger negative values.

Comment: @dilithium actually it won't (although it also wont give the mathematically correct answer for a negative or indeed fractional exponent) - it returns 1 for all zero *or negative* `x`.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix it will stop at 0 for positive values of x. Btw, by getting larger, I think you meant "smaller" as `-1` is the greatest negative value.

Comment: @newoart as thefourtheye said, just remove `=` and you'll be good to go, for positive values of x at least.

Comment: @ozgur yeah, I was definitely off on the infinite recursion.  Regarding the terminology, [I don't think you are correct](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/102357/23771) - but I'd be interested if you have a reputable source.