# Delete Leaf node in a dict for each iteration

Tags: python

I have a sample JSON like:

```
{'key1': {'key2': 2, 'key3': 1, 'key4' : 1}}
```

and I would like to remove each leaf node once and print the JSON using python.

For that, I have the code for printing all the leaf nodes. But, can someone help write for me the code for dynamically remove a leaf node - one at a time

```
def print_all_leaf_nodes(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for item in data.values():
            print_all_leaf_nodes(item)
    elif isinstance(data, list) or isinstance(data, tuple):
        for item in data:
            print_all_leaf_nodes(item)
    else:
        print data
```

input:

```
{'key1': {'key2': 2, 'key3': 1, 'key4' : 1}}
```

Output:

```
{'key1': {'key3': 1, 'key4' : 1}}
{'key1': {'key2': 2, 'key4' : 1}}
{'key1': {'key2': 2, 'key3': 1}}
```

i.e for each iteration, remove a key value pair if its leaf node.

Note: even i am able to get the key path from parent , but not sure how to delete the exact element .

For example if the json is

```
{ "key1" : { "key2" : { "key3": "value1", "key4" : "value2" }}}
```

i have the recursive function which returns me a string

```
key_to_be_removed = "key1.key2.key4"
```

but i am not sure how to delete key4 using this string.

please help.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have three distinct problems:

1. Detect leaf nodes in a tree.
2. Remove key-value pairs from a dictionary depending on some condition.
3. Do this recursively down a tree.

You have the leaf node detection working. For the latter two, I would recommend you read up on [dictionary comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

#### Remove Certain Values

To make a copy of a dictionary with certain values removed, you can use an `if` within a dictionary comprehension:

```py
def foo(d):

    return {
        key: value
        for key, value in d.items()
        if some_condition(key, value)
    }
```

where `some_condition` is

#### Recursion

This is [a broad topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214531/basics-of-recursion-in-python). In the case of recursively applying a method to a dictionary and its values, you can simply include a recursive reference in your dictionary comprehension:

```python
def foo(d):

    return {
        key: foo(value)
        for key, value in d.items()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you have a dict like the below:

```
 g = {
  2: 3,
  4:
      {
          3: 4,
          34: {
              36: 5,
              8: 5,
              7: 9,
              9: 7
          },
          8: 9,
          9: {
              3: 4
          }
      },
  89: 3
  }
```

This dict rapresent a general tree structure where each node could point to an item or a subtree.

If you need to iterate the tree and return the tree without a leaf for each iteration, you could use a generator. You can take advantage of the fact that python do not deep copy the dicts, so if you pass a dict to a function and than you pop an element inside the function you also pop an element outside the function:

## This code is not tested please test it

```
# dict, void list -> dict, list
# find the deepest subtree in a nested dict and return the subtree and the path
# to find it. If there isn't subtree return the same dict and a void list
  def _mostNestedSubTree(tree, nodes):
      for key in tree:
          if isinstance(tree[key], dict):
              nodes.append(key)
              return _mostNestedSubTree(tree[key], nodes)
      return tree, nodes


  # dict, list -> dict
  # pop a nested element from a dict (tree) following the path in a list (nodes)
  def _recursivePop(tree, nodes):
      if len(nodes) > 1:
          print(tree, nodes[0])
          tree = tree[nodes[0]]
          return _recursivePop(tree, nodes[1:])
      else:
          print(tree, nodes[0])
          tree.pop(nodes[0])
          return tree


  def removeOneLeaf(tree):
      mostNestedDict, nodes = _mostNestedSubTree(tree, [])
      while mostNestedDict != tree:
          if len(mostNestedDict) > 1:
              mostNestedDict.pop(list(mostNestedDict)[0])
          else:
              _recursivePop(tree, nodes)
          mostNestedDict, nodes = _mostNestedSubTree(tree, [])
          yield tree
```

Another way could be create an object that better rapresent your tree, for example you can start noting that you can rapresent `g` with something like the below:

```
myTree = {
    tree: [3, 4, 5, 5, 9, 4],
    nodes: [2,4,[3,34,[36,8],8,9,[9,[3,4]]]]
    }
```