# More pythonic way of repetitive nested list comprehension

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, nested, list-comprehension

I want to create an empty NxNxN list in Python.
The way I'm doing it now is as follows:

```
cells = [[[[] for _ in range(N)]
              for _ in range(N)]
              for _ in range(N)]
```

There must be a better way to write this, the repetition of the "for _ in range(N)" part is a bit horrible.

Any ideas as to how this can be done?

Comment: if you are tagging this with [multidimensional-array], you might consider using `numpy`.

Comment: Note that `None` would probably be a better inner element than `[]` for an "empty NxNxN" list. Using `[]` is less efficient and much more prone to accidentally indexing too deep.

Comment: @BrendenPetersen: Not `list`. If you need a nested list, that'd be `np.empty([N, N, N]).tolist()` (which makes lists all the way down, and uses Python scalars instead of NumPy scalars), but keeping the array is probably better.

Comment: In other words, are you planning to use true multidimensional arrays (which python `list` objects are not) of numerical data, and plan to do numerical calculations with it? Because then you should *definitely* be using `numpy`. On the other hand, if you actually want to use `list` objects, then I would not suggest using `numpy` simply for neat-one-liners.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Not at all numerical, this is to be used for a neighbor-cell implementation (i.e. in Molecular Dynamics calculations). Since it will use instances of a self-defined class and not just numbers, numpy seems to be a bit unfitting.

Comment: @pelegs yes, totally. Then I suggest sticking with vanilla `list` objects. Unfortunately, other than doing something like `r = range(N)` outside, and doing `[[[[] for _ in r] ...]]` then I don't know what else to suggest

Comment: How big is `N`?

Comment: @alex not more than 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid manually writing comprehensions for each dimension, here is a recursive approach:

**Code**

```
import copy
import itertools as it


def empty(item, n, dim=3):
    """Return a matrix of `n` repeated `item`s."""
    copier = lambda x: [copy.deepcopy(x) for _ in it.repeat(None, n)]
    if not dim:
        return item
    return empty(copier(item), n, dim-1)
```

**Demos**

```
>>> cells = empty([], 3)
>>> cells
[[[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]],
 [[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]],
 [[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]]
```

Nested items are separate objects:

```
>>> cells[2][2][1] = "hi"
>>> cells
[[[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]],
 [[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]],
 [[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], 'hi', []]]]
```

Elements can be any object:

```
>>> empty("", 2)
[[['', ''], ['', '']], 
 [['', ''], ['', '']]]
```

Control the final dimension (`dim`), e.g. N x N, `dim=2`:

```
>>> empty("", 2, dim=2)
[['', ''], ['', '']]
```

---

**Details**

`empty()` is a typical [recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214531/basics-of-recursion-in-python) where the *base case* returns an `item`, and the *recursive call* is made on the `copier()` function.

```
# Equivalent
def copier(x):
    return [copy.deepcopy(x) for _ in range(n)]
```

The latter is similar to the OP's example, but each item is copied in order to return unique objects.  Should the item be a nested container, a [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) is applied to each element. If unique elements are not critical, you may consider the following implementation for `dim=3`:

```
def empty(item, n):
    """Return an (n x n x n) empty matrix."""
    f = ft.partial(it.repeat, times=n)
    return list(map(list, map(f, map(list, map(f, [item]*n)))))
```

Comment: Can you explain what the code is doing?  What is `ft.partial()`?

Comment: This will put the same empty list everywhere. See `cells = empty([], 3); cells[0][0][0].append("hi");print(cells)`

Comment: @L3viathan, thank you for your observation.  I have revised the answer to return unique elements.